# Не отображается текст в пдф-файле

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Пишу следующий код, используя библиотеку iText:

```
import com.itextpdf.io.image.ImageData;
import com.itextpdf.io.image.ImageDataFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.*;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.AreaBreak;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Image;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;

public class TemplateForPdf {

    public Document createPdf(String dest) {
        try {
            PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(dest);
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
            pdfDocument.addNewPage();
            Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
            return document;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong with document creating...");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void addAreaBreakFont(Document document) {
        AreaBreak areaBreak = new AreaBreak();
        document.add(areaBreak);
    }

    public void addLogo(Document document) {
        try {
            String pathToImage = "C:\\Users\\dalum\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\MgXdLgHx6MY.jpg";
            ImageData imageData = ImageDataFactory.create(pathToImage);
            Image image = new Image(imageData);
            document.setMargins(85.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 20.0f);

            image.scaleAbsolute(270, 115);
            document.add(image);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong with image...");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void addTitleText(Document document, String sum) {
        document.add(new Paragraph("Система быстрых платежей"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TemplateForPdf template = new TemplateForPdf();
        Document document = template.createPdf("C:\\Users\\dalum\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\testPdf.pdf");
        template.addLogo(document);
        template.addAreaBreakFont(document);
        template.addTitleText(document, "8000");
        document.close();
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что текст не отображается в файле, а картинка отображается. Сможете помочь с решением данной проблемы? Пробовал также варианты с установкой шрифта и размера, не помогло